# Centering Drop Down Button

Tags: html, css, dropdown, dropdownbox

I am a newbie and just learn about coding. I got stuck on a pretty simple thing I guess. How do I center a drop down button in a page? This is the HTML code.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  min-width: 110px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 110px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did not use any CSS or JavaScript for this drop down button.

Should I also use CSS and JavaScript for this code to run well?

Please kindly advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

(
In a real world scenario you'll be applying this to the container element and not to entire body)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  min-width: 110px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 110px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Yes, I should apply those codes to container element.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Yes, I should apply those codes to container element.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the position of the drop down to absolute and set the left and top.

```
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this simple method too:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This needs to be on the parent (`body`)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  min-width: 110px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 110px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

.dropdown{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   border:solid 2px green;
   height:100vh;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```